# Is Portapapeles the correct translation for Clipboard?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

In technical terms, what is the correct way to refer to a computer's Clipboard in Spanish? The automated translators say it's "Portapapeles"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, *portapapeles* is the correct translation; [here](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=portapapeles) it is its meaning, according to the RAE:

> portapapeles.
>
> 1. m. Inform. Depósito temporal en la memoria de una computadora donde se coloca información para utilizarla posteriormente.

As you can see, *portapapeles* is a temporary deposit in a computer's memory to store information for a later use.

As a historical note, the word *portapapeles* was only recently accepted by the RAE and it will officially "appear in society" in the 23rd edition of the DRAE.

Comment: What do you mean "appear in society"?  The word has been used by Spanish speakers for sometime.  The DRAE by its own admission doesn't record every valid word in the Spanish language.